# Silverlight 4 Getting Datacontext for ObservableCollection<T> Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a DataContext for a grid that is basically an ObservableCollection. In the code behind I want to iterate through the grid's Datacontext and store each line item into an sharepoint point list. The problem I'm encountering is that I can't seem to access that Datacontext's ObservableCollection. The ObservableCollection was defined in the viewmodel and has been passed to a childwindow which adds to it. Now back in the parent window's code behind I want to access it. I can see that it has values during debug. Just not sure how to cast the Datacontext into an ObservableCollection again.

```
gridNominees.DataContext
```

[image]

Here's basically the application
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of T, then just cast it like any object reference.

If the form deals with ObservableCollection<Nominee>:

```
var nominees = gridNominees.DataContext As ObservableCollection<Nominee>;
```

Comment: The ObservableCollection<Nominee> doesn't exist in the code behind, it was created in the ViewModel. does that mean I have to create the exact class in the code behind?